# Relative Chow groups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, algebraic-k-theory, chow-groups

Most cohomologies have the notion of *cohomology with support on a closed subspace*, and also *cohomology with compact support*. In general, for any morphism $f\colon Y\to Z$ the inverse image fits into a long exact sequence
$$
\cdots \to H^*(f)\to H^*(Y)\xrightarrow {f^*} H^*(X) \to H^{*-1}(f)\to\cdots .
$$
The groups $H^*(f)$ are usually called the *relative cohomology* of $f$.

My question is the following:

> Are there relative Chow groups of a morphism?

So far I have only found definitions for the Chow groups with support in [this paper](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ijm/1255987675) and in the fourth section of Gillet-Soulé *Arithmetic intersection theory*  ([click here](https://eudml.org/doc/104073)) but, is there a general definition?

Note that there is in fact the relative $K$-theory of a morphism and the relative motivic cohomology of a morphism...

Comment: It's probably not the most direct way to do it, but mirroring what happens in homotopy theory, you could take the cofiber of the morphism in the stable motivic homotopy category (or equivalently in Voevodsky's derived category of motives) and then the motivic cohomology of it.

Comment: Thank you, Denis.Your comment has led me to edit the question so that it is now more clear. Yes, the relative Chow groups should coincide on regular schemes with the relative motivic cohomology you mention. But, is there a description with cycles?

Comment: have you looked at construction 2.1 of the coniveau tower paper of Levine (at least for closed subschemes)?

Comment: If you want to have a complex of algebraic cycles that computes the cohomology in question then you have to choose complexes that compute higher Chow groups of $X$ and $Y$ such that $f$ "induces" a morphism of these complexes. It seems that to obtain a "reasonable" construction of this sort you have to assume that $f$ is flat.